# Facebook DealSpot not work on my Application

Tags: javascript, facebook-credits

I have a question about DealSpot.

As the [Facebook API Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/)
suggests, I want to add DealSpot in my game. I've tried the [tutorial way to embed DealSpot](http://help.trialpay.com/credits/2011/07/29/integrating-dealspot-outside-of-your-game-swf/), but it's not working. The icon does not display.

So I checked [Ravenwoodfair](http://apps.facebook.com/ravenwoodfair/)
and copied its code to my application. It's working fine.

The code is below:

```
TRIALPAY.social.render_dealspot_swf
({
id: "trialpay_video",
app_id: "120563477996213",
onOfferUnavailable: "removeTrialPaySwf('trialpay_video')",
mode: "fbpayments",
width: 250,
height: 100,
touchpoint: 2
});
```

But if I change the `app_id` to my own app id, it's not working.

So how do I use DealSpot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use DealSpot in an app that is new or not publicly available, we will first need to register your Facebook App ID in our system.  If you send us the name and App ID of any apps you are trying to use DealSpot on, we would be happy to help you get set up.  Once your App ID is registered, you should have no problems using the code on http://help.trialpay.com/credits/ to set DealSpot up in your game.

Please respond to merchantsupport (at) trialpay (dot) com with your app information and any other questions that you may have.

Best,

Evan
TrialPay Merchant Services